# Function is called twice upon ng-blur and form submission

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/0urOJd3ut4ZzgpoKaEZP?p=preview) I have a form with an input field and a button. The input field's `ng-blur` and the form submission call the same function `validate()`. Problem is that when the cursor is on the input field AND the user clicks on "Submit" the function is triggered twice, as there's a blur when the focus passes to the button. In that scenario, I need the function to be called once.

If you look at the `console.log` you'll see how the function is triggered twice. Any ideas how to fix this?

HTML

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="validate(2)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="someField" ng-blur="validate(1)" />
  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('example', []);

app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.validate = function(x) {
    console.log("field validated - " + x);
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's I would like to solve this. I put a `submitted` variable which determines whether `form` is submitted or not. So, in the `validate` function, we first determine whether `submitted` is true or not. But, the important point here is we would need to make it `false` when we complete the API call. Something like this:

```
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.submitted = false;
  $scope.validate = function(x) {
    if($scope.submitted === true) {
      return;
    }
    $scope.submitted = true;
    console.log("field validated - " + x);
    // change $scope.submitted back to false in success and error callback of 
    // the API call
  };
});
```

This solution has another side benefit. It stops users from submitting the form twice (using multiple clicks on submit button?)

We could have utilized `formName.$submitted` too but here one of the function calls will have it and another wouldn't.

Here's [updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N9TCjlOU9dJ4SJ8UW0Mt?p=preview)

Comment: the problem here is that you need to set `submitted = false` at the end of the function, and if you do that it will be run twice, look at this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/u7nDuMKiLE4WBI2qkj6P?p=preview)

Comment: the fix is to use `$timeout` when you set `submitted = false`, can you update your answer?

Comment: @ps0604 you don't have any API calls to make on submit? generally, most cases people have that. using `$timeout` is a little dirtier solution

Answer (score 0):

that's obvious, but you can always discriminate on the basis of event type, just pass an extra `attribute` denoting the type of event

**EDIT : `ng-change` instead of `ng-blur`** (description in comment)

`html`

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="validate(2)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="someField" ng-change="validate(1)" />
  <br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`js`

```
$scope.validate = function(x) {
  console.log("field validated - " + x);
};
```

Comment: your solution does not avoid the function to be called twice

Comment: or you may use `ng-change="validate(1)"` this will not let `ng-blur` trigger on `ng-submit`

Comment: I cannot use ng-change as that will trigger the validation for each character changed and the validation function is an http call.